# Compiler does not see my concrete types

Tags: c#, .net, generics, automapper

Hi I have create a class that uses generics.Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterMappings : IRegisterMappings
    {
      public virtual void CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<TFrom, TTo>();
        }

        public void PostRegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        public void CreateGetUpcommingLessons<GetUpcomingLessons_Result , UpcomingLessonDTO>()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
}
```

It seems that in my case the compiler does not see GetUpcomingLessons_Result and UpcommingLessonsDTO as concrete types.

I have added the using statements for them but resharper tells me that they can be removed because they are not user.

How can I make the compiler see that GetUpcomingLessons_Result and UpcommingLessonsDTO are concrete types?

**EDIT**

Here is my case I am trying to create a wapper around the Mapper function of Autommapper.
And that what the first two methods are for.

My problem is that I have a case where my target has one more property.This is my source:

```
public partial class GetUpcomingLessons_Result
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ModuleInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentInstanceId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EventDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLastName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherGender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LessonNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my destination:

```
public class UpcomingLessonDTO
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int? ModuleInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentId { get; set; }
    public int StudentAssignmentInstanceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLastName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherGender { get; set; }
    public int? LessonNumber { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    // calculated fields
    public string TeacherOfficialName { get; set; }
}
```

I would need to tell the mapper to ignore TeacherOfficialName name.Until now this was easy I would have just wrote it like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But after creating the wrapper I need  to create another method for this case , that's why I need the concrete types of GetUpcomingLessons_Result and UpcomingLessonDTO.

Comment: concrete types? What do *you* think that means?

Comment: classes that I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the generic types from `CreateGetUpcommingLessons` signature:

```
public void CreateGetUpcommingLessons()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```

The way you have it now has the compiler using `GetUpcomingLessons_Result` and `UpcomingLessonDTO` as generic types (it will use the types that were entered by the user) and not the actual types. To make it more clear, your current implementation is equivalent to this one:

```
public void CreateGetUpcommingLessons<TValueA, TValueB>()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TValueA, TValueB>().ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```

Comment: This can not be done I still need to keep the mapping in my configuration file

Comment: I need to be able to call something like this in my configuration file : m_RegisterMappingsapper.CreateGetUpcommingLessons.<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>() and then be able in my the RegisterMappings class to call Mapper.CreateMap<GetUpcomingLessons_Result , UpcomingLessonDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.TeacherOfficialName, opt => opt.Ignore());

Comment: Hmm...you are right but If I add dest.TeacherOfficialName I get a buil d error ... I need to somehow be able to cast it to the right type